# How to remove elements with duplicate class after infinite scroll append

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm implementing an AJAX based infinite scroll function with jQuery. When the infinite scroll appends to the DOM, some of the resulting new divs may be duplicates because other users adding other comments to the same page can upset the mysql ordering.

So, I need to remove any duplicate comments that are added to the page as a result of the infinite scroll append.

format is

```
 <div class = "comment 1">comment text</div>
```

So any duplicates would be

```
 <div class = "comment 12">comment text</div>
 <div class = "comment 12">comment text</div>
```

Essentially, all I'm looking for is a way to loop through all divs with "comment" in the class, and delete any divs that have more than one occurance of comment **and** number, such as "comment 12" in the above example, while retaining at least one copy.

How do I accomplish this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: does the infinite scroll library you're using have postInit function or callback you can use?

Comment: plain js: document.getElementsByClassName('class-name') return an array;you may keep arr[0] or arr[arr.length -1], and drop the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but something like this?

```
$('.comment').each(function() {

    var currentclass = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('comment', ''));

    if ($('.comment.' + currentclass).length > 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }

});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/5w33E/

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating over the comments by class and removing classes of comments that are already listed:

```
  var matches = [];

  $("div[class^='comment']").each(function () {
    var thisClass = this.className;
    if (matches.indexOf(thisClass) > -1) {
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      matches.push(thisClass);
    }
  });
```

The "`^=`" operator matches any classes that begin with 'comment'.